# Trying to remove @angular/animations but material dialog requires it

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-animations

I realised I was only using `@angular/animations` in one place in my project, so I replaced with a purely css solution and removed it from my project, along with `BrowserAnimationsModule`.

I got this error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: The target entry-point "@angular/material/dialog" has missing dependencies:
 - @angular/animations
```

I was under the impression that if a library I was using had a dependency, that would be handled in their package.json, and that I dont need to add every dependencies dependency to my project.

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing everything right.

The point is, that some packages don't want to bring their dependencies to your project, because, most likely, you will already have them. Thus they declare them as `peer dependency` and rely on you.

You can find some explanations at the npm [official documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#peerdependencies) regarding the peer dependency.

Unfortunately, this mean that you will be not able to get rid of them, unless you are using the code that requires such dependency.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm a little confused though - as you say it's most likely my project will have it, well what if not? Should it just break or should it not fall back to installing it as a dependency of that library?

Comment: @BenTaliadoros When you are installing something that requires peer dependency, npm will automatically check if it exists. If yes - it will install silently, if NOT - you should see the warning in console: `this project requires ....`
I never saw any warning in case of removing peer dependency later.

Comment: But please don't trust me, simply try to install the dependencies one more time with the removed @angular/animations. You should see the warning.